Find $m∡⁢⁢$. in a triangle right below
In a right triangle $ABC m(∡=90^\circ)$ an internal point $"P"$ is marked such that; $AB = BC = AP$ and $m∡⁢⁢=∡⁢⁢$.
Calculate $m∡⁢⁢$.
(Answer:$15^\circ$)
I try:

$\angle PCB \cong \angle PAC = \theta$
$\angle PBC = \alpha$
$\angle PBA  = 90^o - \alpha(I)$
$\angle BAC \cong \angle ACB = 45^o $
$\triangle BAP: \angle BAP = 45^\circ -\theta$
$\therefore \angle PBA =\frac{135^\circ +\theta}{2}(II)$
$(I)=(II): 90^\circ -\alpha = \frac{135^\circ +\theta}{2} \implies \alpha = \frac{45-\theta}{2}$
$\angle CPA = \theta+ 45^\circ -\theta+90^\circ =135^\circ$
$\therefore \angle BPC = 360^\circ -(135^\circ + \frac{135^\circ +\theta}{2}) = \frac{315^\circ -\theta}{2}$

Can you show that $P$ is unique with the given properties? Then take the square with an equilateral triangle constructed inside it on one side, as in one our your own post, then own answer in the last time.

@dan_fulea But how, I don’t think this can be easily constructed like last time.

@dan_fulea  I thought about constructing an equilateral triangle with vertex at P and the base being parallel to BC drawn by A, but I couldn't demonstrate that the side PD would have the point exactly on this parallel to BC.

Such a $P$ exists, and is unique with the following continuity argument. Let $P$ move on the perpendicular bisector of $BP$ from the mid point of $B$ "upwards" up to the mid point of $AC$. For each $P$ let $\alpha(P), \beta(P)$ be the angles$$\begin{aligned}\alpha(P) &=\widehat{PBC}\ ,\\beta(P) &=\widehat{PAC}\ .\end{aligned}$$The function $f(P)=\alpha(P)-\beta(P)$ is continuous, and for an obvious geometric argument also increasing. It has different signs at the extremities of the considered interval, so there exists a unique point $P^$ with the property $f(P^)=0$. You have "that $P^*$".

There was a time when i complained about such "minor things". You seem to take some very special books from some very special years and regions of the world map. Somewhere else, in other books, and in some other times geometry is done "right" in the sense of more precision. Usually, some configuration of points is given, for instance following a construction, one object at one time. In (all of) your problems from this book your "picture" is given "at once". I have problems with this didactically. (You will not learn right.) Then please address existence, e.g. by an explicit construction.

For simpler algebra, let
$$\lvert AB\rvert = \lvert BC\rvert = \lvert BP\rvert = x$$
Since $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles right-angled triangle, and using what you've determined, we also have
$$\lvert AC\rvert = \sqrt{2}x, \;\; \measuredangle APC = 135^{\circ}$$
The law of sines with $\triangle ACP$ gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sin\measuredangle ACP}{\lvert AP\rvert} & = \frac{\sin\measuredangle APC}{\lvert AC\rvert} \\
\frac{\sin(45^{\circ} - \theta)}{x} & = \frac{\sin 135^{\circ}}{\sqrt{2}x} \\
\sin(45^{\circ} - \theta) & = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\sin(45^{\circ} - \theta) & = \frac{1}{2} \\
45^{\circ} - \theta & = 30^{\circ} \\
\theta & = 15^{\circ}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Using your result for $\alpha$ in terms of $\theta$, we then get
$$\alpha = \frac{45^{\circ} - \theta}{2} = \frac{45^{\circ} - 15^{\circ}}{2} = 15^{\circ}$$

Thanks my friend..

Construct $D$ such that $ABCD$ is a square. The condition $\angle =\angle $ implies $\angle APC=135°$. Hence $P$ lies on the circle with center $D$ and passing through $A$.
But $P$ also lies on the circle with center $A$ and passing through $B$ (because $AB=AP$) and $APD$ is thus an equilateral triangle. Hence:
$$
\angle ABP=\angle APB=\angle DPB-\angle DPA=135°-60°=75°
$$
and $\angle PBC=90°-\angle ABP=15°$.


Excellent..thanks
